# How to remove the wrapping of flex class item in bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have the following code, I want to remove the flex wrap and want to align the items nicely

```
<div
    className={`${
        isSmallScreen
            ? `d-flex flex-column gap-2 `
            : `d-flex flex-row  justify-content-between gap-4 `
    }`}
>
    <div
        className={`${
            isSmallScreen
                ? `d-flex flex-row  justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2`
                : ``
        }`}
    >
        <label for="primaryPrice">Price</label>
        <input
            id="primaryPrice"
            value={primaryPrice}
            type="number"
            onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Price"
        />
    </div>
    <div
        className={`${
            isSmallScreen
                ? `d-flex flex-row  justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2`
                : ``
        }`}
    >
        <label for="primaryDiscountedPrice" className="flex-nowrap">
            Discounted Price
        </label>
        <input
            id="primaryDiscountedPrice"
            value={primaryDiscountedPrice}
            type="number"
            onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Discounted Price"
        />
    </div>
    <div
        className={`${
            isSmallScreen
                ? `d-flex flex-row  justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2`
                : ``
        }`}
    >
        <label for="primaryDiscountedRate" className="flex-nowrap">
            Discounted Rate in %
        </label>
        <input
            id="primaryDiscountedRate"
            value={primaryDiscountedRate}
            type="number"
            onWheel={(e) => e.target.blur()}
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Discount Rate"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

**I am getting output like:**

[image]

**I want like this:**

```
Name               : _____
Discounted Price   : _____
Discount Rate in % : _____
```

It should not wrap and width also should be managed nicely because `justify` prop as clearly seen has no effect and how to avoid wrap ?

Comment: You will need to Create [horizontal forms with the grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/layout/#horizontal-form)

Comment: @HDP No bro, just use `text-wrap` and fix typo in `justify-items-between` to `justify-content-between`,and set width like `w-50` that will solve the problem, why to create all that horizontal forms with the grid , simply